# Recorrer un listBox para recuperar sus valores en C#

Tags: c#, listbox

Tengo un ListBox que carga y funciona como yo quiero.

```
        try
        {
            CargandoListBoxNumeros = true;
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexionBd);
            MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(table);
            listBoxNumeros.DataSource = table;
            listBoxNumeros.DisplayMember = "NUMERO";
            listBoxNumeros.ValueMember = "NUMERO";
            CargandoListBoxNumeros = false;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error de carga de numeros de la tabla oronoz de dboronoz" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexionBd.Close();
        }
```

Ahora lo que quiero es recorrerlo para que me muestre unas imágenes según el número del ListBox, pero no hay manera.

He probado varias formas y esta funciona parcialmente: solo lee el primer ítem.

```
private void buttonCargaMiniaturas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                        
            string miniatura = "";
            
            for (int i=0; i < listBoxNumeros.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                miniatura = "00000" + listBoxNumeros.Text;
                miniatura = miniatura.Substring(miniatura.Length - 6, 6);
                string MidresImagen = "Z:\\Midres\\Midres" + miniatura.Substring(0, 2) + "\\" + miniatura + ".jpg";
                pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(MidresImagen);
               if (i > 12) { break; }

            }
        }
```

También necesito que `PictureBox` me funcione con el índice "i" pero no encuentro cómo.
En vez de poner pictureBox3 necesito poner `picutreBox(i)`.

Comment: Me falta saber donde pintas el listbox y que datos recibes para poder emularlo, también, me falta saber en donde tienes el boton `CargarMiniaturas` porque si dices que te lo hace una vez puede ser que solo recojas un item o que te lo sobreescriba, comprueba si es el ultimo el que pinta, en ese caso te lo está sobreescribiendo

Comment: No entiendo nada absolutamente de tu problema... que queres hacer? que tiene que ver el segundo codigo con el primero? que es ese if dentro del for?? que queres que haga cargar miniaturas si todo carga al mismo lugar? un control no puede ser un array, porque no haces un array de imagenes si queres?

Comment: El primer codigo es el de carga del listBox. El segundo al pulsar el boton debe de leer el listBox, cojer las referncias de las imagenes y cargarlas en el pictureBox al que no se como ir cambiando el numero en cada iteracion.El if dentro del for es para colocar solo las 12 primeras imagenes si hubiese mas

Comment: Nicolas, el listBox que no tiene problemas coje los datos que cumplen una condicion de una tabla de la base de dato, almacenando numeros (refencias a archivos de imagenes) Se que lo hace una vez porque consigo que me muestre la primera imagen deli listBox pero no las siguientes, es el primero el que pinta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código haces un lazo `for` por lo `Items` del `listBoxNumeros` pero en ningún punto obtienes el valor del `item` con indice `i`, para ello debes usar la propiedad `listBoxNumeros.Items[i]` para obtener un valor diferente por cada `item` del `listBoxNumeros`, teniendo en cuenta que en este caso los `Items` almacenados son de tipo `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Para asignar la miniatura en cada caso a un PictureBox diferente, podrías generarlo de manera dinámica y agregarlo a un panel, que en mi respuesta nombraré `panel_miniatura`.

private void buttonCargaMiniaturas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        string miniatura = "";
        //Limpiamos los controles del panel_miniatura
        panel_miniatura.Controls.Clear();

        for (int i=0; i < listBoxNumeros.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            //En esta linea obtienes el item con indice i
            System.Data.DataRowView row =(System.Data.DataRowView) listBoxNumeros.Items[i];
            miniatura = "00000" + row["NUMERO"].ToString();
            miniatura = miniatura.Substring(miniatura.Length - 6, 6);
            string MidresImagen = "Z:\\Midres\\Midres" + miniatura.Substring(0, 2) + "\\" + miniatura + ".jpg";
            PictureBox pictureBox_miniatura = new PictureBox();
            //Esta linea establece un tamaño del pictureBox_miniatura, que puedes adecuar al tamaño de tus miniatura
            pictureBox_miniatura.Size = new Size(80, 40);
            //Esta linea establece la coordenada superior del pictureBox_miniatura, para evitar que se apilen unos sobre otros
            pictureBox_miniatura.Location = new Point(5, (pictureBox_miniatura.Height + 2) * i);
            pictureBox_miniatura.Image = Image.FromFile(MidresImagen);
            //Esta linea agrega el pictureBox_miniatura al panel contenedor
            panel_miniatura.Controls.Add(pictureBox_miniatura);
            if (i > 12) { break; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Genial, muchas  gracias. Efectivamente siempre me sale System,Data.DataRowView cuando pongo Item[i] pero nunca me da el numero que esta en el listBox. Por otro lado tengo los pictureBox ya creados 12 dentro de ina panel que hago visible o invisible para cada seleccion y me gustaria itinerar por ellos en vez de crearlos cada vez, pero es una solucion que intentaré. Hace tiempo en VB consegui añadir el numero despues del nombre del control pero en C# no lo encuentro. Voy a intentar tu solucion

Comment: pero necesito el indice del pictureBox para cuando pulse en el saber que indice es. algo así        Control = "pictureBox" + i + ".Image";
                        Control = Image.FromFile(MidresImagen);

Comment: Funciona estupendo los de las pictureBox_miniatura. Sigo sin poder leer el listBox, lo he solucuionado leyendo otra vez la tabla con el comando ExecuteReader en vez de data.Fill(table) y el DataSource

Comment: @JorgeOronoz Que bien que te haya sido util, si es así me gustaria que marcaras la respuesta como aceptada y si lo crees justo que le asignes un punto, esa es la unica recompenza para los que dedicamos tiempo a responder las preguntas.

Comment: @JorgeOronoz Para el problema que planteas en tu segundo comentario, "necesito el indice del pictureBox para cuando pulse en el saber que indice es. algo así Control = "pictureBox" + i + ".Image", es más correcto decir, hacer referencia a los pictureBox agregados, para eso seria más conveniente, que plantees una nueva pregunta, así seria mas util para toda la comunidad.

Comment: ok, tomo nota.  Ahora me estoy peleando con borrar los pictureBox para cuando hago otra seleccion.

Comment: @JorgeOronoz Ya que estas avanzando, te reitero la solicitud de que marques la respuesta como aceptada y si lo crees justo, que le asignes un punto, esa es la unica recompenza para los que dedicamos tiempo a responder las preguntas.

Comment: Ahi si que me has pillado. ¿Como se marca la respuesta como aceptada? y ¿como asigno los puntos?

Comment: Ya está, lo encontre, los puntos no salen porque dice que no tengo 15

Comment: @JorgeOronoz Gracias por aceptar la respuesta. Si es cierto que para asignar puntos debes tener un minimo de reputación.